# Is there an equaivalent solver like MATLAB's vpasolve in Python

Tags: python, matlab, solver

I am working on emulating MATLAB code in Python. The problems is Matlab vpasolve's exact implementation is not available in Python. I have used fsolve to solve the equation but the solution is different in MATLAB and Python.

I would like to know if there is any other solver available in Python which can work same as vpasolve.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB code is as follows

```
for i=1:length(wdth_var)
    gp_wdth(i)=gp_org+2*(wdth_org-wdth_var(i));%gap
    N1(i)=k0*wdth_var(i)/2*sqrt(n_e^2-(beta_s/k0)^2);
    N2(i)=k0*wdth_var(i)/2*sqrt((beta_s/k0)^2-n_f^2);
    f1=tan(2*N1(i));
    f2=((N1(i)*N2(i)*(1+tanh(2*N2(i)*(gp_wdth(i)/2)/wdth_var(i))))/(N1(i)^2-(N2(i)^2*tanh(2*N2(i)*(gp_wdth(i)/2)/wdth_var(i)))));
    f3=((N1(i)*N2(i)*(1+coth(2*N2(i)*(gp_wdth(i)/2)/wdth_var(i))))/(N1(i)^2-(N2(i)^2*coth(2*N2(i)*(gp_wdth(i)/2)/wdth_var(i)))));

  n_effe_wdth(i)=vpasolve(f1-f2==0,beta_s,[10 20])
  n_effo_wdth(i)=vpasolve(f1-f3==0,beta_s,[10 20])/k0;
end
```

I want to emulate the exact MATLAB code in Python. When I use the Python's sympy package by code goes in an infinite loop. Later, I used the numpy package the answers are nowhere close to what I get in MATLAB

Python numpy package code:

```
for in range (len(wvl)):
k0wvl = 2*pi/wvl[i]
n_e_wvl_demo = n_e_wvl[i]


f3 = lambda beta_s: np.tan(k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt((n_e_wvl_demo**2 - (beta_s/k0wvl)**2)))) - ((((k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt((n_e_wvl_demo**2 - (beta_s/k0wvl)**2))))) * (k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt(((beta_s/k0wvl)**2 - n_f**2)))) * (1 + np.tanh(2 * (k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt(((beta_s/k0wvl)**2 - n_f**2)))) * (gp_org / 2) / wdth_org))) / (((k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt((n_e_wvl_demo**2 - (beta_s/k0wvl)**2)))))**2 - ((k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt(((beta_s/k0wvl)**2 - n_f**2))))**2 * np.tanh(2 * (k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt(((beta_s/k0wvl)**2 - n_f**2)))) * (gp_org / 2) / wdth_org))))

f4 = lambda beta_s: np.tan(k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt((n_e_wvl_demo**2 - (beta_s/k0wvl)**2)))) - ((((k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt((n_e_wvl_demo**2 - (beta_s/k0wvl)**2)))))* (k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt(((beta_s/k0wvl)**2 - n_f**2)))) * (1 + (1/(np.tanh(2 * (k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt(((beta_s/k0wvl)**2 - n_f**2)))) * (gp_org / 2) / wdth_org))))) / (((k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt((n_e_wvl_demo**2 - (beta_s/k0wvl)**2)))))**2 -  ((k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt(((beta_s/k0wvl)**2 - n_f**2))))**2 * (1/(np.tanh(2 *  (k0wvl*wdth_org/2*(np.sqrt(((beta_s/k0wvl)**2 - n_f**2)))) * (gp_org / 2) / wdth_org))))))

a = (fsolve(f3, [10, 20]))/k0wvl
a_1.append(a[0])

b = (fsolve(f4, [10, 20])) / k0wvl
b_1.append(b[0])
```

I would like to know if there is any other solver available in Python which can work exactly as vpasolve and give same answers as MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

`vpasolve` is not exact, instead it allows you to solve with a higher precision, defined by digits. While MATLAB calls it variable precisions, other areas mostly call it arbitrary precision. You closest equivalent to vpasolve would be using mpmath in python.

If you instead aim for an exact solution using symbolic computation, sympy would be your choice.